# React App Routing Issue: Works on Localhost but Fails on Production (except "/")

Tags: reactjs, routes, deployment, build, netlify

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm encountering a perplexing issue with my React application's routing. The application works flawlessly on localhost, but when deployed to production, only the root path ("/") is accessible. All other routes seem to fail.

Details:

I'm using React Router for navigation.

The application structure is as follows (simplified):

```
import { Box } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./Components/Header/header";
import AdminMain from "./Components/Main/Admin/adminMain";
import AdminQuiz from "./Components/Quiz/adminQuiz";
import AdminQuestions from "./Components/Question/adminQuestions";
import UserMain from "./Components/Main/User/userMain";
import UserQuiz from "./Components/Main/User/userQuiz";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<UserMain />} />

        <Route path="/admin" element={<Header />} />
        <Route exact path="/admin/categories" element={<AdminMain />} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/admin/categories/:categoryid/quiz"
          element={<AdminQuiz />}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/admin/categories/:categoryid/quiz/:quizid/questions"
          element={<AdminQuestions />}
        />
        {/* </Route> */}
        <Route exact path="/quiz/:id" element={<UserQuiz />} />
      </Routes>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ChakraProvider>
        <App />
      </ChakraProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Additional Information:

I have verified the following:
Base URL is correctly set.
Server is configured to handle client-side routing.
No console errors or warnings in the development environment.
The issue persists after clearing the browser cache.

Website URL
https://musical-biscotti-ee3046.netlify.app/

GitHub Repository:
https://github.com/huzaifa-aslam/alex-quiz-app-front-end.git

How can the community help me troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions you can provide to help me identify and fix this routing problem in my production environment.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you add redirect rule in netlify before deployment? https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/07/22/deploy-react-apps-in-less-than-30-seconds/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not using `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom`

```js
<BrowserRouter>
<Box>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<UserMain />} />

    <Route path="/admin" element={<Header />} />
    <Route exact path="/admin/categories" element={<AdminMain />} />
    <Route
      exact
      path="/admin/categories/:categoryid/quiz"
      element={<AdminQuiz />}
    />
    <Route
      exact
      path="/admin/categories/:categoryid/quiz/:quizid/questions"
      element={<AdminQuestions />}
    />
    {/* </Route> */}
    <Route exact path="/quiz/:id" element={<UserQuiz />} />
  </Routes>
</Box>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I am using `BrowserRouter` in index.js. I updated my question you can re-check.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add redirection rules in your project. In your `public` folder create a file called `_redirects` (no file extension) and add the following line `/*    /index.html   200`. Retry deployment after making the changes.

Comment: I did the same but still not working

Comment: Check it here: https://github.com/BParvatkar/alex-quiz-app-front-end. Deployment: https://main--candid-caramel-f11fa8.netlify.app.

Comment: You can try hitting the /admin route in this deployment.

Comment: great!. its working now.
but i am uploading on namecheap, so i am facing same issue

Comment: Then you will have to see how to handle the redirections in namecheap. Probably via .htaccess file.